# XSLT - Looking For A Way to Count Number Of Results Matching an If Statement inside an xsl:for-each-group loop

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xslt that is processing a large data set and grouping the results based on an ID contained in the dataset. Inside the xsl:for-each-group loop I have an if statement that prints out a data line for each group that matches the criteria in the if statement. I have been asked to add a counter to the file to display the number of data lines written to the output file and I have been grinding my gears and have not yet found answer. I feel it is sitting right in front of me and figured I'd try asking here. Thanks in Advance for any help.

Below are my group and if statements

```
<xsl:variable name="ACCOUNTED_DEBIT_AMT">
<xsl:sequence select="format-number(sum(current-group()/../wd:ACCOUNTED_DEBIT_AMT), '#.00')"/>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:if test="$ACCOUNTED_DEBIT_AMT != '.00'">
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

As you failed to include source XML, I based my solution on the following sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<items>
  <item ID="1">
    <ACCOUNTED_DEBIT_AMT>5.10</ACCOUNTED_DEBIT_AMT>
  </item>
  <item ID="1">
    <ACCOUNTED_DEBIT_AMT>5.20</ACCOUNTED_DEBIT_AMT>
  </item>
  <item ID="1">
    <ACCOUNTED_DEBIT_AMT>5.30</ACCOUNTED_DEBIT_AMT>
  </item>
  <item ID="2">
    <ACCOUNTED_DEBIT_AMT>5.20</ACCOUNTED_DEBIT_AMT>
  </item>
  <item ID="2">
    <ACCOUNTED_DEBIT_AMT>5.30</ACCOUNTED_DEBIT_AMT>
  </item>
</items>
```

To sum values of a node (e.g. `ACCOUNTED_DEBIT_AMT`) in the current
group, you should write:

```
<xsl:variable name="amount"
    select="sum(current-group()/ACCOUNTED_DEBIT_AMT)"/>
```

Your solution contains `..` after `current-group()` and this is probably wrong.

Using `..` you are "jumping out" of the current group to the parent node.
Do you want to sum up `ACCOUNTED_DEBIT_AMT` nodes - **direct children**
of this parent?

Note also that I did't use `format-number` so far, as it is (IMHO) more clear
to use in a comparison just the sum and not its formatted representation.

`format-number` function can be used later, to format the output value.

Below you have a working solution for the above source XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="items">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="item" group-by="@ID">
        <group>
          <xsl:attribute name="ID" select="current-grouping-key()"/>
          <xsl:variable name="amount"
            select="sum(current-group()/ACCOUNTED_DEBIT_AMT)"/>
          <amount>
            <xsl:if test="$amount &gt; 0">
              <xsl:value-of select="format-number($amount, '0.00')"/>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="$amount = 0">
              <xsl:text>None</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
          </amount>
        </group>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

One more remark: Actually it is not clear whether you want to **sum up**
something (values of a node in the current group, as you wrote in
your example) or **count** items included in the current group
(as you wrote in the title).

In the latter case use `<xsl:value-of select="count(current-group())"/>`
in the `for-each-group` loop.

Or maybe you want to count items in the current group which meet some condition,
e.g. *amount > 5*? In such a case write:

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(current-group()/.[ACCOUNTED_DEBIT_AMT &gt; 5])"/>
```